# XPath to get Nth child item of a node, *failing* if it doesn't have a requested name

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the XML:

```
<sharedItems>
    <d v="2017-07-10T09:11:02"/>
    <d v="2017-07-10T09:11:03"/>
    <m/>
</sharedItems>
```

How can I create an XPath query to get the third child of the sharedItems node, having "m" name here? I.e., I only want the query to succeed if and only if the third child is "m", and fail otherwise.

Basically, I want to assert the children order; so possibly another XPath-based approach would solve this better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be (untested)...

```
/sharedItems/*[3][self::m]
```